# how do i get gwt form submit to open in a new window with set dimensions?

Tags: gwt, resize, submit, new-window

I'm using GWT and I need to have the results of a form submission open in a new window with a set width and height.  I can get it to open in a new tab, but don't know how to get it to load in a new window, nor how to set the width and height.  Here's my code :

```
 @UiHandler({"myGWTButton"})
    protected void myGWTButtonClicked(ClickEvent click) {
      click.preventDefault();
      FormPanel form = new FormPanel("_blank");
      form.setAction("www.mydomain.com");
      form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
      form.setEncoding("multipart/form-data");
      TextArea params0 = new TextArea();
      params0.setName("foo");
      params0.setValue("bar");
      form.setVisible(false);
      form.add(params0);
      RootPanel.get().add(form);
      form.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that I was over-thinking things by trying to use GWT. I solved my problem by relying on native javascript.

```
 @UiHandler({"myGWTButton"})
    protected void myGWTButtonClicked(ClickEvent click) {
    click.preventDefault();
    openPopupWindow("www.mydomain.com", 'bar');
}

native void openPopupWindow(String url, String val) /*-{
       var windowName = '' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000) ; //we need some name to reference it later, so assign a random number as the name (make sure the number doesn't have a decimal because IE will choke on it)
       var popupWindow =  window.open('', windowName, 'width=550,height=350,resizeable,scrollbars');
       var form = document.createElement("form");
       form.setAttribute("method", "post");
       form.setAttribute("action", url);
       form.setAttribute("target", windowName);
       form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
       var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "foo");
       hiddenField.setAttribute("value", val);
       form.appendChild(hiddenField);
       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(form);
       while(!popupWindow){
         //wait for popupwindow to open before submitting the form
       }
       form.submit();

    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Forms seem to get their results in a separate iframe. Problem is, you can't really interact with this iframe because of cross-site restrictions (SOP). So I'm not sure there's a way to do this.

Could you not use a HTTP request instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have possible solution for you *if you can use GET method instead of POST*.

```
@UiHandler({"myGWTButton"})
protected void myGWTButtonClicked(ClickEvent click) {
  click.preventDefault();

  Window.open(new UrlBuilder()
        .setHost("www.mydomain.com")
        .setParameter("foo", "bar")
        .buildString(), "_blank", "width=200,height=200");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I can't use GET because of the size of the data I'm sending.

Comment: @Boundless Do you submit to the same domain:port as your original page? If no does the server you submit to allow cross-domain requests? Because if you answer yes to some of that questions you can submit to hidden frame after that you can access frame result from your original page and open new window passing result from frame to the window.

Comment: I do submit to the same domain.  I ended up solving the problem using native javascript. I posted the solution if you want to see it.